# make notifcation live and be aware of event in android

Tags: applications, line, social-networking-service

I would appreciate if you can help me about following problem.
actually i have some social networking app in my android phone.

however i will notified just about some of them as the right as new event occur.
Let me I explain it by an example, consider you are using IMO App. As soon as one of your contact send message you in that, you will be notified.

in fact notification of new event will show up in your screen, however some other app, just when show these notification that you open related app in your phone. Like Line App.

I also check for latest version and check some related setting. However i would be appreciate if anyone can help me about this problem. actually i want to be notified as soon as possible not late. let me know If there is any special setting here too. Thanks.

Comment: LINE notifications appear immediately. Did you disable notifications or something?